# Calculate medication adherence: cumulative pill shortage

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

It is difficult to find a proper way to calculate medication adherence. Knowing that no perfect sollution exists, I want to calculate the number of days a patient could definitely not have taken his medication, because he didn't have any. I want to do this for every time medication was issued.

I have pharmacy data that looks like this:

```
x <- data.frame(
  patient_id = 1,
  issue_date = as.Date( "1990-01-01" ) + cumsum( c( 0, 35, 30, 25, 30 ) ),
  no_tablets = 60
)

  patient_id issue_date no_tablets
1          1 1990-01-01         60
2          1 1990-02-05         60
3          1 1990-03-07         60
4          1 1990-04-01         60
5          1 1990-05-01         60
```

I can off course calculate the difference in `issue_date`s, and see if it's equal to `no_tablets / 2` (bidaily dose) a patient had to take.
But if a patient collects his drugs earlier, he can then wait longer for the next time than this period, because he has a stock of medication.

I tried to do the calculations on a cumulative number of days and a cumulative number of doses, and then sum all non-negative cumulative pill shortages. However, if I patient is late once and then picks up the medication precisely on time, this number still stands and is then counted multiple times.

Do you have any other ideas how I can do this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it looks like this patient's supply of pills continues to exceed the number of days between refills. Without an example of what you're desired output would like, I think the script below may suffice:

```
x <- data.frame(
  patient_id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)),
  issue_date = c(rep(as.Date( "1990-01-01" ) + cumsum( c( 0, 35, 30, 25, 30 ) ), 2)),
  no_tablets = c(rep(60, 5), rep(31, 5))
)

y <- data.frame(
  patient_id = c(1, 2),
  pills_per_day = c(2, 1)
)

z <- merge(x, y, by = "patient_id")

library(data.table)
z <- data.table(z)
z[, days_excess := (no_tablets/pills_per_day) - ifelse(patient_id == shift(patient_id, 1, type = "lead"), 
                                                   -as.integer(issue_date - shift(issue_date, 1, type="lead")), 
                                                   NA)]

print(z)
   patient_id issue_date no_tablets pills_per_day days_excess
 1:          1 1990-01-01         60             2          -5
 2:          1 1990-02-05         60             2           0
 3:          1 1990-03-07         60             2           5
 4:          1 1990-04-01         60             2           0
 5:          1 1990-05-01         60             2          NA
 6:          2 1990-01-01         31             1          -4
 7:          2 1990-02-05         31             1           1
 8:          2 1990-03-07         31             1           6
 9:          2 1990-04-01         31             1           1
10:          2 1990-05-01         31             1          NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In my example the patient has to take 2 pills a day, so sometimes the number of days exceed the number of day's tablet supply.

Comment: @Jasper I edited my answer to add an additional patient and added different pill quantities per day for the two patients. Looking at it again, I also removed the cumsum function and just looked at the monthly excess for each refill.

Comment: Thanks again Brandon. The problem is that a patient is allowed to have a pill deficit when he has a "stock" left from a previous excess. So I think I need to do something cumulatively.